# Django null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following problem:

I am try to save the user and profile but When I try to post in my database the following  error occur:

```
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (16, 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00, null, colegio monserrat, femenino, null, primero, social, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, Ciencias mundo contemporáneo, Historia de la filosofía, Lengua catalana y literatura I, Lengua catalana y literatura II, Lengua extranjera I, Lengua extranjera II, Lengua castellana y literatura I, Lengua castellana y literatura II, fisica, matematicas, quimica, matematicas, matematicas, matematicas, matematicas, fisica, Educación física, Filosofía, null, Historia).
```

My models is the following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
birth_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
sex = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
school = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SCHOOL_CHOICES)
schoolCode = models.IntegerField(null=True)
bachelorCourse = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=COURSE_CHOICES)
bachelorModality = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=COURSE_MODALITY_CHOICES)

password = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
password2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)

obligatorySubjectOne1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Lengua catalana y literatura I')
obligatorySubjectTwo1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Lengua castellana y literatura I')
obligatorySubjectThree1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Lengua extranjera I')
obligatorySubjectFour1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Ciencias mundo contemporáneo')
obligatorySubjectFive1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Educación física')
obligatorySubjectSix1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Filosofía')

optionalSubjectOne1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
optionalSubjectTwo1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
optionalSubjectThree1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
optionalSubjectFour1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)

obligatorySubjectOne2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Lengua catalana y literatura II')
obligatorySubjectTwo2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Lengua castellana y literatura II')
obligatorySubjectThree2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Lengua extranjera II')
obligatorySubjectFour2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Historia de la filosofía')
obligatorySubjectFive2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default='Historia')

optionalSubjectOne2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
optionalSubjectTwo2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
optionalSubjectThree2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
optionalSubjectFour2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
optionalSubjectFive2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)

avatarChoose = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)  # imageField
interest = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
interestOne = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
interestTwo = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
university = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
universityOne = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
universityTwo = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50, choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES_OPTIONALLY)
meanCourse = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

The ModelForm in the forms.py is the following:

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    labels = {
        "first_name": "Nombre",
        "last_name": "Apellidos",
        "email": "Correo"
    }

    widgets = {
        "first_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        "last_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        "email": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }


# build the some edit profile register variables
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        Profile.obligatorySubjectOne1 = "Castellano"
        Profile.obligatorySubjectFive1 = "Castellano"

        fields = ('birth_date',
                  'sex',
                  'school',
                  'bachelorCourse',
                  'bachelorModality',
                  'optionalSubjectOne1',
                  'optionalSubjectTwo1',
                  'optionalSubjectThree1',
                  'optionalSubjectFour1',
                  'optionalSubjectOne2',
                  'optionalSubjectTwo2',
                  'optionalSubjectThree2',
                  'optionalSubjectFour2'
                  )
        labels = {
            "birth_date": "Fecha de nacimiento",
            "sex": "Sexo",
            "school": "Escuela",
            "bachelorCourse": "Curso de bachillerato",
            "bachelorModality": "Modalidad de bachillerato",
            "optionalSubjectOne1": "Escojer Optativa 1B",
            "optionalSubjectTwo1": "Escojer Optativa 1B",
            "optionalSubjectThree1": "Escojer Optativa 1B",
            "optionalSubjectFour1": "Escojer Optativa 1B",
            "optionalSubjectOne2": "Escojer Optativa 2B",
            "optionalSubjectTwo2": "Escojer Optativa 2B",
            "optionalSubjectThree2": "Escojer Optativa 2B",
            "optionalSubjectFour2": "Escojer Optativa 2B"
        }
        widgets = {
            "birth_date": forms.SelectDateWidget(empty_label=("Choose Year", "Choose Month", "Choose Day")),
            "bachelorCourse": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "bachelorModality": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectOne1": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectTwo1": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectThree1": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectFour1": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectOne2": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectTwo2": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectThree2": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
            "optionalSubjectFour2": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'})
        }
```

And finally my views where I save the object created is the following:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        new_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        # Set the chosen password
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
        # Save the User object
        new_user.save()
        new_profile.save()

        return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': user_form, 'new_profile': profile_form})
else:
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    profile_form = ProfileEditForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

This is all of code that I think you need it to know the problem. Before, the register part of my code, it worked correctly, I don't know if the problem can be caused for database or why are not  all instructions in the views.

If you can help me, thanks you in advance.

The part in bold of traceback is the following:

```
    /home/web_unithinks/unithinks/account/views.py in register
            new_profile.save() ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
new_profile 
<Profile: Profile for user verver>
new_user    
<User: verver>
profile_form    
<ProfileEditForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(birth_date;sex;school;bachelorCourse;bachelorModality;optionalSubjectOne1;optionalSubjectTwo1;optionalSubjectThree1;optionalSubjectFour1;optionalSubjectOne2;optionalSubjectTwo2;optionalSubjectThree2;optionalSubjectFour2)>
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/account/register/'>
user_form   
<UserRegistrationForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(username;email;first_name;last_name;password;password2)>
```

Comment: As an aside, the lines `Profile.obligatorySubjectOne1 = "Castellano"` and `Profile.obligatorySubjectFive1 = "Castellano"` look incorrect. It's not clear what you are trying to do there. I would remove those lines.

Comment: Yes, I put when I was making proves.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `new_profile.user` before you save it:

```
new_profile.user = new_user
new_profile.save()
```

Comment: If you are still getting the error, please make sure you have saved your code and restarted the server after making any changes, and then update your question with your current code.

Comment: I am sure that I have save the code and restarted the server. The error is the same, the error message doesn't change.

Comment: Then I can't help, because the code you have shown shouldn't give that error if you set `new_profile.user` before saving. The full traceback might give some clues about why the error is occuring.

Comment: Yes, I modify the error and add the part in bold of the traceback

Comment: That’s not the full traceback. Use the button to switch the format so that it’s easy to copy/paste, then include the full traceback. Also, update your question to show your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Profile object needs a user associated before it's saved, this would be something like

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            #####################
            #SOMETHING LIKE THIS#
            #####################
            new_profile.user = new_user
            new_profile.save()

            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': user_form, 'new_profile': profile_form})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm()
        return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Comment: you may need to resync the user model

Comment: Exist any command to resync the user? or you refer to delete my migrations and redoing the migrates again?